# Get value if object or string if string in jq array

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a JSON object that looks like this:

```
[{"name":"NAME_1"},"NAME_2"]
```

I would like an output of

```
["NAME_1", "NAME_2"]
```

Some of the entries in the array are an object with a key "name" and some are just a string of the name. I am trying to extract an array of the names. Using

```
jq -cr '.[].name // []'
```

throws an error as it is trying to index .name of the string object. Is there a way to check if it is a string, and if so just use its value instead of .name?

Comment: @Inian I've edited the question to include the expected output. The input works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```bash
echo '[{"name":"NAME_1"},"NAME_2"]' \
| jq '[ .[] | if (.|type) == "object" then .name else . end ]'
```

```
[
  "NAME_1"
  "NAME_2"
]
```

Ref:

- https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ConditionalsandComparisons
- https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#type

---

As @LéaGris comments, a simpler version

```bash
jq '[ .[] | .name? // . ]' file
```

- https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ErrorSuppression/OptionalOperator:%3f
- https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Alternativeoperator://

Comment: Or as a try catch mechanism combining the alternative operator `//` with the error cancellation `?`: `jq --argjson a '[{"name":"NAME_1"},"NAME_2"]' -n '[ $a[] | .name? // . ]'`

Comment: Thanks @Léa, it was the `?` operator that I was missing in my experimentation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `type` function which returns `"object"` for objects.

```
jq '.[] | if type == "object" then .name else . end' file.json
```

To get the output as array, just wrap the whole expression into `[ ... ]`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the error suppression operator [with `?`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#.%5B%5D?), `map` and `scalars`

```
jq 'map( .name?, scalars )'
```

Note that by using `scalars`, it is assumed that other than objects with `name`, all others are names of form `NAME_*`. If there are other strings as well, and you need to exclude some of them you might need to add some additional logic to do that. e.g. using `startswith(..)` with a string of your choice.

```
map( .name?, select( scalars | startswith("NAME") ) )
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/2lj6Tw7xbRU)

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples only, please try following `jq` code. Using [`tostream`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Streaming) function here to get the required values from requirement.

```
jq -c '[.[] | tostream | if .[1] != null then .[1] else empty end]' Input_file
```